# Creating an instance of a class, before class is defined?

Tags: python, class

Here's an example of my problem :

```
class bar() :
    spam = foo()
    def test(self) :
        print self.spam.eggs
        pass

class foo() :
    eggs = 50
```

The issue (I assume) is that I'm trying to create an instance of a class before the class is defined. The obvious solution is to re-order my classes, but I like to keep my classes in alphabetical order (maybe a silly practice). Is there any way to define all my classes simultaneously? Do I just have to bite the bullet and reorder my class definitions?

Comment: This is a reasonably reason why you should separate classes by file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alphabetical order is a silly idea indeed;-). Nevertheless, various possibilities include:

```
class aardvark(object):
    eggs = 50

class bar(object):
    spam = aardvark()
    def test(self) :
        print self.spam.eggs

foo = aardvark
```

and

```
class bar(object):
    spam = None  # optional!-)
    def test(self) :
        print self.spam.eggs

class foo(object):
    eggs = 50

bar.spam = foo()
```

Note that much more crucial aspects than "alphabetical order" include making all classes "new style" (I've done it in both examples above) and removing totally redundant code like those `pass` statements (I've done that, too;-).